# ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis in Python Script

Tags: python, sql, oracle, arcpy

I am using a python function in ArcGIS's arcpy module called 'MakeQueryTable'.

http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/make-query-table.htm

Basically, it leverages Oracle sql querying to build a table. I've build a script and I am getting the following error:

> [ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis]

First off, I've gone line for line and there doesn't seem to have any missing parenthesis. Again, after going line for line and commenting out each one and executing the script to see where the problem first occurs, it seems like it occurs after I uncomment the `group by` statement and remove the LISTAGG statement. So, when I eliminate the group by statement and change the line with the LISAGG function to `["MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE.DESCRIPTION, ''Work_Type_Items']`, the script runs. When I allow the group by statement, the script throws this error.

Unfortunately, I need the group by statement to produce the table I need. The LISTAGG function also relies on grouping to run properly. If I were to build this same query in Oracle SQL Developer, it will run. I just thought I'd come on here and see if someone with a better SQL background can suggest why this error is throwing.

Here is the script:

```
tableList = ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW", "MTA.MTA_TENURE_EVENT_XREF", "MTA.MTA_EVENT", "MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT", "MTA.MTA_SOW_WORK_TYPE_XREF", "MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_CODE", "MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE"]

fieldList = [["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_NUMBER_ID", 'Tenure_Number'],
             ["MTA.MTA_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID", 'Event_Number'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION", 'Tenure_Type'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_SUB_TYPE_DESCRIPTION",'Tenure_Sub_Type'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TITLE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION", 'Title_Type'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.ISSUE_DATE", 'Issue_Date'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.GOOD_TO_DATE", 'Good_to_Date'],
             ["MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.OWNER_NAME", 'Owner_Name'],
             ["LISTAGG(MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE.DESCRIPTION, '; ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE.DESCRIPTION)", 'Work_Type_Items'],
             ["MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE.DESCRIPTION", 'Work_Type_Items'],
             ["MTA.MTA_EVENT.DATA_ENTRY_DATE", 'Data_Entry_Date'],
             ["MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.AMOUNT", 'Amount']]

whereClause = """MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_NUMBER_ID = MTA.MTA_TENURE_EVENT_XREF.TENURE_NUMBER_ID and
             MTA.MTA_TENURE_EVENT_XREF.EVENT_NUMBER_ID = MTA.MTA_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID and
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID = MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID and
             MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID = MTA.MTA_SOW_WORK_TYPE_XREF.EVENT_NUMBER_ID and
             MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.MTA_WORK_TYPE_CODE = MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_CODE.MTA_WORK_TYPE_CODE and
             MTA.MTA_SOW_WORK_TYPE_XREF.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE = MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE.MTA_WORK_TYPE_ITEM_CODE and
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.MTA_EVENT_TYPE_CODE = 'SOW' and
             MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.mta_work_type_code = 'P' and
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.DATA_ENTRY_DATE between (sysdate-365) and (sysdate) and MTA.MTA_EVENT.COMMITTED_IND = 'Y' and
             MTA.MTA_TENURE_EVENT_XREF.TENURE_NUMBER_ID = 230428
             group by
             MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_NUMBER_ID,
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID,
             MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.OWNER_NAME,
             MTA.MTA_WORK_TYPE_CODE.DESCRIPTION,
             MTA.MTA_SOW_EVENT.AMOUNT,
             MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,                 MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_SUB_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
             MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TITLE_TYPE_DESCRIPTION,
             MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.ISSUE_DATE,
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.DATA_ENTRY_DATE,
             MTA.MTA_EVENT.GOOD_TO_DATE"""

keyField = "MTA_SPATIAL.MTA_ACQUIRED_TENURE_SVW.TENURE_NUMBER_ID; MTA.MTA_EVENT.EVENT_NUMBER_ID"

lyrName = "Test_Table2"
# Make Query Table...
arcpy.MakeQueryTable_management(tableList, lyrName,"USE_KEY_FIELDS", keyField, fieldList, whereClause)
```

Comment: There's a missing comma after the first group by column. Does adding that comma change the result?

Comment: Thanks @Peter M. I just fixed that, but it didn't resolve the issue. The post has been updated to include the comma.

Comment: Is there an easy way to see the entire query once it's been assembled by the library? Perhaps by turning on a trace at the DB server side? I haven't used that tool in a long time, but there must be some way to do that I guess.

Comment: Also, if you keep the group by clause but don't include the listagg, does it work? I would add a single space between ) and WITHIN GROUP just to be sure it's not causing a parsing problem.

Comment: I like your though on printing out the compiled function to see how it's executed, but I'm not sure how to do that. If I keep the group by clause and remvoe the LISTAGG function, there error still occurs.

Comment: Is the field separator for keyField definitely semi-colon and not comma? Would the statement execute if you just put one field there?

Comment: Thanks again Peter. I've tried just one key field as well with the same resulting error. Also, according to the help document I posted above for the function, the keyfields are supposed to be seperated by a semicolon.

Comment: OK Mike.. I'm sure the solution can be uncovered. You might find that the library's SQL builder tried to append extra clauses to the where clause (which would fail as you've already closed out the where clause with the group by). -- Here's a link about back-end trace: http://carymillsap.blogspot.com/2011/01/new-paper-mastering-performance-with.html -- You could also see if the Python/Oracle API or the GIS library has a switchable front-end trace or debug mode

Comment: At this point I don't see any symbol errors (except I would try using a single " instead of the triple " at the beginning and end of the where clause, as the manual's own examples don't write it that way).